# Python Panda valueError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using the PySimpleGUI , import csv file and run the python function

Below is the example

```
A      B        C

1       2       3
```

I expect the csv result:

```
A

1
```

But It gives me an error

Below is my PySimpleGUI and python:

```
import pandas as pd

import PySimpleGUI as sg

import sys

sg.theme('Beige')

# ------ Menu Definition ------ #

menu_def = [['File', ['Open', 'Save', 'Exit', 'Properties']],

            ['Edit', ['Paste', ['Special', 'Normal', ], 'Undo'], ],

            ['Help', 'About...'], ]

# ------ Column Definition ------ #

column1 = [sg.Text('Column 1', background_color='#F7F3EC', justification='center', size=(10, 1))],

layout = [

    [sg.Menu(menu_def, tearoff=True)],

    [sg.Text('Welcome ', size=(30, 1), justification='center', font=("Helvetica", 25), relief=sg.RELIEF_RIDGE)],

    [sg.Text('_'  * 80)],

    [sg.Text('File Selection', size=(35, 1))],

    [sg.Text('Your CSV file', size=(15, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='right')],

    [sg.In(), sg.FileBrowse()],

    [sg.Open(), sg.Cancel()]

]

if len(sys.argv) == 1:

    event, values = sg.Window('Everything bagel', layout, default_element_size=(40, 1), grab_anywhere=False).read(close=True)

    fname = values[0]

    df = pd.read_csv(fname, skiprows=0)

    df.drop(['B','C'], axis=1, inplace=True)

    df.to_csv("File_Result.csv", index=False)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\JeanBaptiste\PycharmProjects\JB_Python_Script\GuiTest_12.py", line 26, in <module>

    df = pd.read_csv(fname, skiprows=0)

  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 680, in read_csv

    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 575, in _read

    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 933, in __init__

    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1217, in _make_engine

    self.handles = get_handle(  # type: ignore[call-overload]

  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 670, in get_handle

    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(

  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 427, in _get_filepath_or_buffer

    raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Are you certain ```fname``` isn't None?

Comment: It looks like that you clicked the close button of window, it return a dictionary `values` which maybe like this, `{0: None, 'Browse': None}`, so you got `None` for `fname` which assigned as `values[0]`. Need to set `if-elif-else` statement for all conditions to prevent any case to be failed.